# search-api solr is nor performing OR search

Tags: search

I am trying  to provide the OR feature for my solr search . when user type words, the search should be able to return result which matches with any word present in the query . 
I changed the default operator from AND to OR in my schema.xml , 
After change it looks :`<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>` 
however , It still doesn't perform OR search . The result is empty when I type multiple words .
I am using search_api with solr  I have aplplied the changes to my drupal solr configuration as well as solr server .what could be wrong ? any pointers is really appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the hook :

```
hook_search_api_solr_query_alter(array &$call_args, SearchApiQueryInterface $query)
```

Have a look to your query & params and see if the solr query is what you were expected, if it's not you can alter it.